# Copying Range into new Workbook FileDialog prompt not working

Tags: excel, vba, savefiledialog

I'm trying to copy some specific cells to a new Workbook that I'm prompted to make while running the VBA script. I keep getting Object doesn't support this property or method on wsI.Range("Y2:AF2882), what's wrong with my code?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Export1()

    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As Variant
    
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add
    
    Filename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Filename, "Excelfile (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")


    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Ark1")
        Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("SVK stationer")
        .SaveAs Filename
        
        wsI.Range("Y2:AF2882") _
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a space in `wsI .Range("Y2:AF2882")`, after `wsI`, as you can see (copied from your code). Did you copy your code from the module, or write it by hand? It should be `wsI.Range("Y2:AF2882") _`.

Comment: Otherwise, the code line does  not have any meaning. It should be continued on the next code line. This is the meaning of "_" character.

Comment: I copied it, but I think I had it without a space at first but missing the `_`. I've added that, but now I get the same error in .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy. Might be a stupid question but do i need a `_` before that as well?

Comment: And did you test it as I suggested?

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? I am trying to deduce what is missing. The code probably tries to use `With wsI.Range("Y2:AF2882")` (no ending "_") followed by the two lines starting with a dot, but it misses a `End With` after `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`, I think...

Comment: @FaneDuru It's a mix of copy and rewrites, so there is a good posibility I've forgotten an `End With` or have a  wrong sequence in my code to be honest. I'm not that experienced with coding/VBA. Do I need to have two separate `With` one for the `wbI` first and then one for the `wbO` then?

Comment: Didn't I clearly stated that in my above comment? Is it something unclear there? If yes, what is not clear? If not, did you try it as I suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated re comments

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Export1()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Arki"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SVK stationer").Range("Y2:AF2882")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        wb.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Excelfile (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
        'wb.Close False
    End With

End Sub
```